# Teradata - Get current row end date based on following row start date

Tags: sql, date, teradata

I am looking to get an end date for the current row based on the following row's start date

Example Input

```
ID Date
1 1/19/2022
1 1/25/2022
1 1/26/2022
2 2/1/2022
```

Output:

```
ID StartDate EndDate
1 1/19/2022 1/24/2022
1 1/25/2022 1/25/2022
1 1/26/2022 CurrentDate
2 2/1/2022 CurrentDate
```

How can we do this in Teradata

Comment: Where is the '1/24/2022' EndDate in the Expected Result coming from?

Comment: Based on the following rows start date minus 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select id,
   LEAD(datecol, 1, current_date) 
   over (partition by id
         order by datecol
from mytable
```

The lead returns the next row's value and current date for the last row in a partition.